# How to share a wimax network with Hos-PC and Hyper-V VM's?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection

i use internet using a Wimax USB Dongle Modem. I want to use that net also on hyper-V Vm's.  I have shared internet connection by clicking on it's properties. Should i configure a proxy server configuration to access internet on VM's by using a proxy tool like CCproxy, can't i do it without a proxy server setup?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out later why My VM couldn't detect host Network as DHCP was not on in the VM. Then i ran the auto troubleshooter in the VM windows  server and it fixed it automatically.